# How to make a button reappear after 24 hours

Tags: javascript

I have this code below to hide a button but I would like to show the button again after 24 hours. How do I do this?

```
<input type="button" id="points" value="Points" onClick="action();" />

<script>
var hidden = false;
function action() {
    hidden = !hidden;
    if(hidden) {
        document.getElementById('points').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have any code to share?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :) But keep in mind that SO is a community that helps, and no one will do all the work for you. Please show us some code you messed up with and we'll be glad to help improve it...

Answer (score -1):

```html
<input type="button" id="toggler" value="Toggler" onClick="action();" />
<input type="button" id="togglee" value="Togglee" />

<script>
    var hidden = false;
    function action() {
        hidden = !hidden;
        if(hidden) {
            document.getElementById('togglee').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('togglee').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: with this, does HTML `make button that when we click it will hide and come after 24 hours` as OP asked ?... don't think so...

Comment: what part of `it will hide and come after 24 hours` did you actually not understand ? :) OP asks for a TIME range

Comment: @OldPadawan please try to help me if you understood

Comment: @jayash : a cookie ? set it when clicked, then use it again when user comes back ? no ?

Comment: @OldPadawan no, tell if it is possible with mysql db

Comment: @jayash : if you use a DB, you record the click with Ajax, but it has to be a registered user (IP alone won't be good enough I believe). And check whenever user comes back?